# Restrict column in listview from being greater than X (NotifyPropertyChanged not working)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

**Here is how my program behaves as I type numbers:**

[image]

I have a listview that is binded to an observable collection. Here is my code: ( you may skeep this part the classes are very simple)

**Class Item:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Represent each row in listview
/// </summary>
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    void UpdateSum()
    {
        Sum = Col1;// + col2 + col3 etc
    }

    decimal _Col1;
    public decimal Col1 //                                         ||
    {                   //                                         ||
        get             //                                         ||
        {               //                                         ||              
            return _Col1; //                                       ||                              
        }                 //                                       ||              
        set               //                                       ||                
        {                 //                                    \  ||   /                        
            if (value > 100)  //                                 \ || /                                
            {                 //                                   \/                  
                Col1 = 100;  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  HERE why does the listview does't update!!!!!!!!
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Col1");
            }else
            {
                _Col1 = value;
            }
            UpdateSum();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Col1");
        }
    }

    decimal _Sum;
    public decimal Sum
    {
        get
        {
            return _Sum;
        }
        set
        {
            _Sum = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("Sum");
        }
    }
}
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Collection = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Collection.Add(new Item());
            listView2.DataContext = Collection;
            listView2.ItemsSource = Collection;
            listView2.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Listview in xaml:**

```xml
 <ListView Name="listView2" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Column1" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Col1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Sum" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Sum, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

---

### Anyways why when I update `Col1=100` it does not update in the listview! Also note how the sum comes to be 100 and not 1000.

I don't want column1 to be greater than some number x. In my real program that number changes dynamically and I calculate it inside the Item class.

How can I fix this?

---

---

### Edit

I found something interesting... If I start typing different numbers taks a look at what happens: I will just type 5 in this example:

[image]

### It works in step 3!!!

once it is equal to 100 it stops working...

Comment: You shouldn't be raising property changed twice, the one at the end is enough.

Comment: This shouldn't really help you, but in your setter for Col1, change `if(value > 100){ Col1=100; ...` into `if(value > 100){ _Col1=100; ...`

Answer (score 1):

I made it work!!!  I changed:

```
 Text="{Binding Col1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

for:

```
 Text="{Binding Col1, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

### But I need to update the property when the textbox changes so this migh be a solution for someone else...

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're trying to change the property value during DataBinding. The problem is that WPF tries to be smart and not listen on property changes raised during DataBinding. 
This is a well know problem with numerous workarounds:

- [Change value in setter property when using WPF two-way databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857116/change-value-in-setter-property-when-using-wpf-two-way-databinding)
- [Data binding issue in WPF: with solution](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/DataBindingIssueInWPFWithSolution.aspx)

Although MS made some fixes in WPF4.0 see: [WPF 4.0 Data Binding Change (great feature)](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/wpf-4-0-data-binding-change-great-feature/)

But I did some quick testing and none of them is working in your case because of the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

However I can came up a very dirt workaround which is "works":

```
public decimal Col1
{
    get { return _Col1; }
    set
    {
        //Change the property value based on condition
        _Col1 = value > 100 ? 100 : value;
        UpdateSum();
        //HACK: Simulate that the property change not fired from the setter
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
            .BeginInvoke(new Action(() => NotifyPropertyChanged("Col1")));
        //HACK: Cancel the bindig based on condition
        if (value > 100)
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

See it action:

[image]

Notice: after typing the third 5 the cursor moves the the beginning of the TextBox and it remains there if you type the next 5.

I don't think that the above mention code should be the solution, I've just played a bit. I think you should go with `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` and do the binding manually from the textbox `TextChanged` event... But I'm afraid there is no clean solution for your problem.

Comment: am I supposed to wrap the `//HACK: Cancel the bindig based on condition if (value > 100) throw new Exception();`  in a try catch block? if I do I get the same behavior... Maybe I am doing something wrong...

Comment: You don't need the try catch in theory. I've created my repro with using only your sample code. And I've only changed the `Col1` property... I've used .net 4.0 client profile...

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is a bug in the TextBox where if you change the bound value this way it only updates the first characters of the TextBox. For example, if you entered 1005 it updates the first 3 characters to 100 (but ignores the 5).

Fixing this is simple, Ive added another property to you Item class, and changed the TextBox binding slightly:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int maxValue = 100;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    void UpdateSum()
    {
        Sum = Col1;// + col2 + col3 etc
    }

    decimal _Col1;
    public decimal Col1 
    {                  
        get            
        {                         
            return _Col1;                             
        }                          
        set                       
        {                       
            if (value > maxValue)                                
            {                                
                Col1 = maxValue; 
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Col1");
            }
            else
            {
                _Col1 = value;
            }
            UpdateSum();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Col1");
        }
    }

    public int MaxValueWidth
    {
        get
        {
            var tmp = (int)Math.Log10(maxValue) + 1;
            return tmp;
        }
    }

    decimal _Sum;
    public decimal Sum
    {
        get
        {
            return _Sum;
        }
        set
        {
            _Sum = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Sum");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that Ive added a property that calculates the maximum chars for the TextBox base on the maximum value.

No all I do is add the Binding

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Col1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="{Binding MaxValueWidth}"></TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I replaced my Item class with the one you posted. I also replaced my TextBox in xaml with the one you posted in here. I still get the same behavior. Maybe it is cause my Textbox is inside a gridview?