# Change Combobox SelectedItem in Bounded property setter of SelectedItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox, 2-way-object-databinding

I have scenario in `Combobox`, We want to change the current `SelectedItem` of `Combobox` when certain value is selected.

**For Instance**: We have designation `Combobox` having values: `CEO`, `Manager`, `Dev`, `QA`..
When `CEO` is selected we would like to change it to `Manager` value.

`SelectedValue` is bound to property in ViewModel.

Comment: Have you tried to change property that is bound to `SelectedValue` in `ComboBox` `SelectionChanged` event? Or change the `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox` in this event.

Comment: In the ViewModel you will be notified on the property binded i.e in `SelectedValue`  if it implements INPC.  On the `Set` you can validate and make the Selection as anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I thought it was a silly question and could be answered without spending much effort :P.  But, it thought me a lesson that WPF is not working the way what I think as always.

### **Here is the sample working solution.**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Width="100" Height="50" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboList}"  SelectedValue="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True}"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ObservableCollection<string> lst = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    lst.Add("CEO");
    lst.Add("Tester");
    lst.Add("president");
    lst.Add("Developer");
    lst.Add("Manager");

    MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel() { ComboList = lst, Selected = "Employee" };
    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifiPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboList { get; set; }

    private string selected;
    public string Selected
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            selected = value == "CEO" ? "Manager" : value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }

}
```

The Key is **`IsAsync=True`** which did the trick here.  Thanks to [Martin Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69824/martin-harris) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/857186/2819451)